# zend framework change meta with ajax

Tags: zend-framework, jquery, meta

In my website with ZF, I get pages with an ajax call.
I want to change the meta tags (author, keywords, description) every time I do a new ajax-call.
I put these setName() method in the ajax-controller but it doesn't fill the meta.

```
$this->headMeta()->setName('description', $description);
$this->headMeta()->setName('keywords', $keys);
$this->headMeta()->setName('author', $author);
```

Is it possible? how is the correct way?

Comment: Have your ajax calls been created in a way that search engines will follow them? If not, what's the point in manipulating data that only search engines will see using Ajax?

Comment: I would like that search engines load this new meta tags. is it possible?